# How to update an attribute ':what_cause' of model user using group of radio button in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to update an attribute ':what_cause' of model user on a page which is in a session. User clicks on one of the 3 radio buttons and corresponding value should be transferred to a method which updates it. 
I wrote following code-

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
    <label>Pratham</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :what_cause, "pratham" %>
    <label>Kali</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :what_cause, "kali" %>
<label>Akshaya</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :what_cause, "akshaya" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save", :controller => "users_controller", :action => "change_cause", :method => "put" %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the code for updation in change_cause method of users_controller.rb-

```
def change_cause
if params[:radio_button] == "pratham"
@user.update_attribute(:what_cause, "pratham")
end
if params[:radio_button] == "kali"
    @user.update_attribute(:what_cause, "kali")
end
if params[:radio_button] == "akshaya"
    @user.update_attribute(:what_cause, "akshaya")
end
end
```

But it is not working. Please enlighten me. I am a newbie in RAILS!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_cause
  @user.update_attribute(:what_cause, params[:user][:what_cause])
end
```

Comment: That prob is sorted I think only that now its showing- "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" but :what_cause has values in it. It is not nill.
May you guess out whats the prob?